# Can I import components from my React Library using folder imports?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

So I built a small React library to use in all my projects without needing the hassle of copy/pasting files everytime a new project comes along.

This is what my file structure in my library looks like:

```
- src
    - Button
        - Button.tsx
        - index.ts
    - Modal
        - Modal.tsx
        - index.ts
        - useModal.ts
    - index.ts
```

My `index.ts` file of my Modal folder contains:

```
export { default as Modal } from "./Modal"
export { default as useModal } from "./useModal"
```

And finally my `index.ts`, the base of the module contains:

```
export { default as Modal } from "./Modal/Modal"
export { default as useModal } from "./Modal/useModal"
export * from "./Modal"

export { default as Button } from "./Button/Button"
export * from "./Button"
```

My question is: Is there some configuration i can setup that allows me to import, from a different project that has this lib installed, from the folders like:

```
import { Button } from "my-lib/Button"
import { Modal, useModal } from "my-lib/Modal"

export default TestComponent() {

    const modal = useModal()
   
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={onClick}/>
            <Modal open={modal.open} onClose={modal.onClose}>
                //children
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Im making the library with vite, here is my vite.config.ts:

```
import path from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import tsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        tsConfigPaths(),
        dts({
            include: ["src/"]
        })
    ],
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name: 'my-lib',
            formats: ['es', 'umd'],
            fileName: (format) => `my-lib.${format}.js`,
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
            output: {
                globals: {
                    react: 'React',
                    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                },
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: You can use `npm link`